# How to get ID of EditorFor with nested viewmodels in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

So I have two nested view models, CreditCard -> BillAddress.
I have a view, "EditBilling", that has EditorFor(CreditCard).  The CreditCard EditorTemplate has EditorFor(BillAddress), and the BillAddress EditorTemplate has EditorFor(BillState).

The end result is a select list with id "CreditCard_BillAddress_BillState".

I need to reference this in javascript, thus need to know the ID.  In other situations, with non-nested ViewModels, I have used the following code:

```
$('#<%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName %>_BillState')
```

The problem here is that the ModelMetadata.PropertyName property is only aware of the current property, not the parent(s).  So I end up with the following:

```
$('#BillAddress_BillState')
```

How does one go about getting the client ID of nested strongly typed helpers?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I've found a solution by looking through the source code of the TemplateHelpers. It seems that ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix yields the full "name" (basically with "." as a separator instead of "_").